# How to increase the quantity within the same product, and how to decrease the quantity?

Tags: php, mysqli

The problem that I encountered was it it cannot increase while I clicking the adding button for the second time, and I don't have the idea of how to do the decrease button.

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])){
if (isset($_SESSION["cart"])){
    $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "id");
    if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)){
        $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
        $item_array = array(
            'id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
        echo '<script>window.location="counter.php"</script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("Product is already Added to List")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location="counter.php"</script>';
    }
}else{
    $item_array = array(
        'id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
    );
    $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
}
```

}

```
<?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
        $query = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image FROM product ORDER BY product_id ASC ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                ?>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <form method="post" action="counter.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>">

                        <div class="product">
                            <img src="img/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" style="width:100px; height:100px">
                            <h5 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?></h5>
                            <h5 class="text-danger"><?php echo "RM " . $row["product_price"]; ?></h5>
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["product_price"]; ?>">
                            <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="+">
                            <input type="submit" name="minus" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="-">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>

<div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th width="30%">Product Name</th>
            <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
            <th width="10%">Total Price</th>
            <th width="17%">Remove Item</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])){
                $total = 0;
                foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $value) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $value["item_name"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $value["item_quantity"]; ?> <a href="counter.php?action1=subtract&id=<?php echo $value["product_id"]; ?>"><input type="submit" name="subtract" style="width:20px; height:25px" class="btn btn-success" 
                                value="-"></td>
                        <td>RM <?php echo number_format($value["item_quantity"] * $value["product_price"], 2); ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="counter.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $value["product_id"]; ?>"><img src="img/icon-delete.png"/></a></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $total = $total + ($value["item_quantity"] * $value["product_price"]);
                }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right">Total</td>
                        <th align="right">RM <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></th>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>

    </div>
```

The output of adding only shows for the first clicked, but it will be displayed "Product is already Added to List" for the second clicked, cannot increase the product quantity. The actual result should be increasing quantity. Same question for the decrease product quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the quantity of the previous addition and add or subtract them together.
You can also use `$_SESSION["cart"]` and store the ID as the index.

You should be able to use: (this isn't tested)

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])){
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'])){$_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] = 0;}
    $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_name'] = $_POST["hidden_name"];
    $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['product_price'] = $_POST["hidden_price"];
    $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] = $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] + $_POST["quantity"];

    header('Location: counter.php');
}
if (isset($_POST["decrease"])){
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'])){$_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] = 0;}
    $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_name'] = $_POST["hidden_name"];
    $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['product_price'] = $_POST["hidden_price"];
    $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] = ( ( ( $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] - $_POST["quantity"] ) > 0  ) ? $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] - $_POST["quantity"] : 0 );

    header('Location: counter.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem perfectly. But how to unset all the error session just now?

Comment: Easiest way is to just clear the array `$_SESSION['error'] = ''` or whatever it was called.

Comment: No problem remember to mark the answer as correct so future users know what helped :)

Comment: The quantity able become negative value

Comment: }else if(!isset($_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'])<= 0){
  echo '<script>alert("Product cannot be reduce anymore")</script>';
  echo '<script>window.location="counter.php"</script>';
 }
is this can check the negative value?

Comment: Just run a check too see if it's smaller than 0? if it is make it = 0

Comment: No that checking if it is set, not its value.

Comment: Check edit, that should replace the value to 0 if negative

Comment: How to check it? What's the code should be look like?

Comment: `$_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] = ( ( ( $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] - $_POST["quantity"] ) > 0  ) ? $_SESSION["cart"][$_GET["id"]]['item_quantity'] - $_POST["quantity"] : 0 );`

Comment: I don't know that I only need this edit, I have been doing if checking. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: How to add each line of record into the database after clicking on the payment button?

Comment: You need to create a new question mate, this one has been solved.

Comment: Oh...Ok, I thought just using this one to ask question. Haha

Comment: May u help me watch trough the new questions that posted yesterday? Cause I can't pass the data to the new page, and don't know if I get the data correctly with my code. @Second2None

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688259/how-to-save-each-line-of-record-into-the-database?noredirect=1#comment96164966_54688259

Comment: Why suddenly there is an error which is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\surfmart1\counter.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\surfmart1\counter.php on line 17

Comment: How to fix that offset as an array issues? @Second2None This is the link that I posted the new questions about the error message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746988/fatal-error-uncaught-error-cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in-stack-tra

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the logic of increment and decrement the quantity.

If you press add button then increase the value of product by 1 and same vice versa. So first of all your need to get the current quantity of the added product and then do the operator add or delete.

```
$_SESSION["cart"][$count]['item_quantity']=$_SESSION["cart"][$count]['item_quantity'] + $_POST["quantity"];  // For add
```

Basic idea given below.

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])){
   if (isset($_SESSION["cart"])){
      $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "id");
       if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id)){
          $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
          $_SESSION["cart"][$count]['item_quantity']=$_SESSION["cart"][$count]['item_quantity']+$_POST["quantity"];
           $item_array = array(
                'id' => $_GET["id"],
                'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
           );
           $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
          echo '<script>window.location="counter.php"</script>';
      }else{
          echo '<script>alert("Product is already Added to List")</script>';
          echo '<script>window.location="counter.php"</script>';
      }
}else{
     $_SESSION["cart"][0]['item_quantity']=$_SESSION["cart"][0]['item_quantity']- $_POST["quantity"];
    $item_array = array(
        'id' => $_GET["id"],
        'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
        'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
    );
    $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but there still got some problem existed.